# i need to parse both the columns using regex but i am not able to. Please advise

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace, regex-greedy

```
Port           Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi1/0/1        2,6,21,25,99,195,197,505,605
Gi1/0/6        2,21,25
Gi1/0/7        2,21,25
Gi2/0/1        2,6,21,25,99,195,197,505,605
Gi2/0/6        2,21,25
```

using this ^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$ is this right?

Comment: So your pattern is ^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$, what is your string to test on? And what language are you working? Java? Python? R?

Comment: Hi it's a table 

Port              Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi1/0/1         2,6,21,25,99,195,197,505,605
Gi1/0/6         2,21,25
Gi1/0/7         2,21,25
Gi2/0/1         2,6,21,25,99,195,197,505,605
Gi2/0/6         2,21,25

using python
the expression that i mentioned is just reading first row of both the columns...

Comment: Try `(?m)^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$`